# How to properly access a scope in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-api

I'm currently using Laravel Passport, and I can verify that there is current token saved by using  `localhost:8000/api/check` that returns json below:

```
{"id":"1c080ff73c6592b8e35630ae36f45f5042c04d9a9ed26a7fafc3793c606484b619ed8792be65a658","user_id":1,"client_id":5,"name":"Personal Access Tokens","scopes":["administrator"],...}
```

But when I tried to use middleware scope for admin using `localhost:8000/api/admin` it returns an error

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [scope] does not exist. in file

---

Here is the **routes/api.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::get('check', 'TeamController@check');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'scope:administrator'], function() {
        Route::get('admin', 'TeamController@index');
    });
});
```

Here's the corresponding functions on **TeamController.php**

```
public function check(Request $request) {
    return auth()->user()->token();
}

public function index(Request $request) {
    return auth()->user()->token();
}
```

Somebody knows what I went wrong?

Comment: sounds like there was no middleware with the alias 'scope' registered ... did you register the middleware the passport docs talk about? (`scopes` and `scope`)

Comment: @lagbox thanks sir!! u pointed it right. U can answer it and I will accept.

Comment: np, good luck and have fun with Laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely did not register the `scope` middleware.

> "Passport includes two middleware that may be used to verify that an incoming request is authenticated with a token that has been granted a given scope. To get started, add the following middleware to the `$routeMiddleware` property of your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file:"

```
'scopes' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckScopes::class,
'scope' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckForAnyScope::class,
```

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Passport - Checking Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#checking-scopes)